# Dismissing multiple view controllers showing wrong view during transition

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a total of 4 UIViewControllers. Each of the Views has a button that when pressed presents the next viewcontroller. When the button on the last UIViewController is pressed it calls dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, , completion: nil) on the rootViewController. When this is called it immediately shows View #2, instead of staying with View #4, as it transitions back to View #1. In the documentation it says that when you do this the top-most view is the only view that will be animated during dismissing, but that's not the case for me? This also happens if i used segues.

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func btnDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        var viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func btnDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        var viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
class ViewController3: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func btnDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        var viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController4") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
class ViewController4: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func btnDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.view.window?.rootViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```